# Magento2.4 when generating an order, how is the payment method saved in the order table

Tags: payment-methods

Magento2.4 custom payment method, when generating an order, how is the payment method saved in the order table

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the sales_flat_order_payment table which contains the payment information for each order (it has a 1:1 relation to sales_flat_order which is the main table for orders). You are looking for the method column.

Comment: What is the code flow for saving the payment method